# Get substring from string in mysql where length of substring is dynamic

Tags: php, mysql

> Discount Coupon XXXXX applied:
>
> where length of XXXXX may varied

Comment: 'Discount Coupon XXXXX applied:' is a value of a field in database table. From that I want 'XXXXX' only.

Comment: Do you think this is enough information for someone to understand your question?

Comment: [preg_match()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: I have one field named 'example' in table whose value is 'Discount Coupon XXXXX applied:' I want only 'XXXXX' from field 'example'.
Is there any way in MySQL to get 'XXXXX'?

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match() to look for the regular expression to trim a string.

```
 int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

You can read more [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), and it would be much better if you provide further information.

Answer (score 0):

> SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( `example` , ' ', -2 ) , ' ', 1 )

Comment: As long as the discount code doesn't contain a space.